# Lebesgue integral of f(x) over R is equal to Lebesgue integral of f(x+t) over R

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

What is the most natural way to show that for Lebesgue-integrable function $f$ we have
\begin{equation}
\int f(x)dx=\int f(x+t)dx?
\end{equation}

Is the following approach correct?

Let $\epsilon>0$. We can find simple function $\psi$ such that $\int|f(x)-\psi(x)|<\epsilon/2$. Then $\psi(x+t)$ is simple function such that $\int|f(x+t)-\psi(x+t)|dx<\epsilon/2$ and $\int\psi(x)dx=\int\psi(x+t)dx$. From here we have
\begin{equation}
\left|\int f(x+t)dx-\int f(x)dx\right|\leq\int|f(x)-\psi(x)|dx+\left|\int\psi(x)dx-\int\psi(x+t)dx\right|+\int|f(x+t)-\psi(x+t)|dx<\epsilon,
\end{equation}
end we are done.

Answer (score 1):

So far you have proved that have
\begin{equation}
\int f(x)dx \to \int f(x+t)dx
\end{equation}

as $ t \to 0.$ But this does not prove what you're trying to prove. If are trying to prove that the Lebesgue integral is translation invariant, do the following:

1. Show that the equality is true for any indicator function, which is obviously true because of the definition of Lebesgue integral and translation invariance of Lebesgue measure.
2. Using finite linearity of Lebesgue integral, show that the result holds for any simple function.
3. Without loss of generality assume that $f$ is non-negative, otherwise, write $f= f^{+}-f^{-}.$  Let's say $f$ is non-negative. Then there exists a monotone increasing sequence of simple function ${s_{n}}$ such that $s_{n} \to f.$ Then apply MCT.

Then you're done. Let me know if you have any questions.

Edit: Since your $\epsilon$ is arbitrary and $t$ is independent of $\epsilon,$ your proof should be good. Sorry for my irresponsible comments.

Comment: Before all that, i have a question. Inequality that i wrote doesn't depend on t. So since epsilon was arbitrary we have equality of integrals. Am i correct? I've actually just used that integral of simple functions is translation invariant like you said i should in step 2, and implicitly used what you said i should do in step 3.

Comment: My bad. Yes, you are correct. Since your $/epsilon$ is arbitrary and independent of $t,$ your proof should be good. I will edit my post soon.

Comment: Also, that what are you suggesting to be done in steps 1,2,3 is more conceptual and probably more natural then what i have done to prove the statement.

Answer (score 0):

The main idea lying under the equality you're interested in, is that the set $x\mapsto f(x)$ and $x\mapsto f(x+t)$ run over, is the same: the whole $\Bbb R$.

This is because $x\mapsto \phi(x):=x+t$ is a diffeomorphism of $\Bbb R$, for each fixed $t$.

Moreover, *the way* these two functions runs over $\Bbb R$ is the same: this is expressed by the fact the derivative of $x\mapsto \phi(x)$ is identically 1.

What I wrote is resumed by the change of variable theorem for integrals:

\begin{align*}
\int_{\Bbb R}f(x+t)dx
&=\int_{\Bbb R}f(\phi(x))dx\\
&=\int_{\underbrace{\phi(\Bbb R)}_{=\Bbb R}}f(y)\cdot\underbrace{(\phi^{-1})'(y)}_{\equiv1} dy\\
\end{align*}